# Power Automate issue

Tags: powerbi

"actions in this flow may result in an infinite trigger loop. please ensure you add appropriate conditional checks to prevent this flow from triggering itself"

How do i fix this issue? [[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n02wk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ltAD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/177aV.png)

Ive tried to add triggers but still not resolved